# Android with AspectJ and building it with Ant on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, aspectj

I'm new to Android and wanted to use AspectJ with it.
I had searched couple articles online and follow the instruction to have it working:
http://blog.punegtug.org/2010/11/adding-aspect-to-android.html

But I wanted to know whether if it's possible to separate the aspects away from the Android project. In the tutorial link above, it has both the Android App and the aspects inside the same project, but in many cases, we wanted to leave the Android Project untouched in its isolating spaces.

Let said I have AndroidProject in my Eclipse workspace, I would like to create a separate projects for my aspects called something like "AndroidAspectProject" which only contains the aspects for it.

I'm not sure whether this would work because it seems we need to let AspectJ compiler inject point cuts and advices to the .class files before creating the .dex files. In this sense, I may not able to do it in a separate project.

Does anyone try with this?

Another related question would be:
Is it possible to have Ant build the AndroidProject with AND without aspects on it?  Can this be done outside of Eclipse?

I'm looking for a way to build different flavours as I'm only injecting pointcuts into the AndroidProject on dev/debug build, but will leave it untouched on release build.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not to do the compile-time aspects is a matter of whether or not you run the aspectj [ant tasks](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/antTasks-install.html). Have separate targets or properties for the AOP- and non-AOP-builds and either build one based on a target name or property, or build them both and change the artifact name.

IIRC Eclipse allows you to specify an Ant target to run on a build.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Would you mind to share a bit how to set this up as sample, so I can see how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Eclipse, this is simple.  Just add AndroidAspectProject to the aspect path of AndroidProject.

Inside of ant, there are several ways of doing this.  But, the simplest is to define 2 targets.  One that uses iajc and the other that uses javac to compile your sources.  You then need to use a little ant magic switch between targets depending on whether you are compiling for dev or for production.

Comment: I guess I would have to make "AndroidAspectProject" as a Android project in Eclipse first right?  Then manually add the AspectJ nature to it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, they have an option for making Android Project as Library, should I just use that instead? Would that work? My ultimate goal is to make some of my aspects classes generic enough to be a library used by other developers in my team.

Thanks!

Comment: Turning your aspects into a library is probably a good long term goal, but that makes it harder to develop and debug them.  Since you would need to jar them up every time you want to use them.

Comment: Hi Andrew, so the best way to use AspectJ in Android project is putting them into the same project, and converting the Android project as Aspect Projects too.  Then make a build flavour when building debug (Eclipse) build vs release (Ant) build?

In my team, we have many Android Apps Projects which used basically the same sets of API, so probably it's better to make it as a library since the pointcuts on most calls are generic Android API calls.

What do you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Andrew, I follow your suggestion for Eclipse, and still couldn't get it to work. Do I need to convert my AndroidProject to AspectJ project first?

Comment: Yes.  If your android project is consuming aspects. then it must be an aspect project.  (There is no aspect path of a project unless it is an aspectj project.)

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried your way to converting the AndroidProject to be an aspect project.
Then I make my AndroidAspectProject as an Android Library. Then In AndroidProject, I added AndroidAspectProject to the Aspect Path, Add AndroidAspectProject as the "Java Build Path", make AndroidAspectProject as "Project Reference" to AndroidProject. 

And I still have this error.
advice defined in org.xbeta.aspects.CallGraph has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch] CallGraph.aj /AndroidAspectLib/src/org/xbeta/aspects line 16 Java Problem

Comment: Andrew, is there a way to contact you offline? I had many suggestions to make the AJDT better working with Android and how we can promote the use of AOP development on Android side. Let me know whether I can contact you via email.

Or if you feel like chatting on a chatroom, we can do that too!

I believe this area is fairly new using AspectJ with Android development and I want to know what we can do to contribute to make this better for others.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure...let's chat about this more.  The best place for this is the ajdt-dev mailing list since there are others who'd want to be in on this conversation. Subscribe here: https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/ajdt-dev

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I will join that mailing list. But would you able to answer my last question regarding to the error?

Comment: The error you are seeing indicates that your advice is not matching anywhere.  Without seeing what the aspect and pointcut is and where you intend it to match, I can't say why you are getting it.  Best to send this to the mailing list, too.